# How can I detect runtime code generation in .NET Core?

Tags: c#, .net-core, reflection.emit

I have an application that's being run on a platform that does not support runtime code generation (i.e. `System.Reflection.Emit`). Any methods that try to generate code throw a `NotImplementedException` at runtime.

Building for and deploying to this platform is incredibly time consuming, so development and testing is done in a standard .NET Core environment, which happily allows runtime code generation. If I accidentally hit a path that causes a third party libraries to generate code, I won't find out until much later, after the new code has been built and deployed.

Is there any way for me to disable code generation in my application, so I can find these code paths during development, when running it on my local machine? It seems like something that should be supported, if for no reason other than security concerns.

Comment: I am thinking of the following, get `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()` assemblies and search for `System.Reflection.Emit` or other assemblies with code generation, if it is present then checking is failed

Comment: I considered that, but it won't work; the assemblies are allowed to (and do) contain calls to `Emit`. I have to make sure that my code avoids the code paths that hit it.

Comment: Could you weave some code (log, exception, etc...) into the third party libraries and use those only during development? [Cecil](https://github.com/jbevain/cecil), [Postsharp](https://www.postsharp.net/framework), [CrossCutterN](https://github.com/keeper013/CrossCutterN) might help.

Comment: Any way you could have the platform for which the build is "incredibly time consuming" as a stripped-down version in a container? Ultimately the only convincing way to test if something will work is to have an test environment that's as representative as possible. One option is to build a self-contained .NET Core app, then replace the supplied `System.Reflection.Emit` assembly with the reference assembly (which contains no implementation) as part of your build step.

Answer (score 0):

Use `RuntimeFeature.IsDynamicCodeSupported` to check for the ability to generate code at all.

Use `RuntimeFeature.IsDynamicCodeCompiled` to check whether the generated code is interpreted or compiled.

These properties are available in .net standard 2.1 and above.